# has been Ving since ... vs. is Ving after

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, present-continuous

Are both the following sentences correct? If so, what's the difference?

> a. Mary has still been lingering in the park since she left the office.

> b. Mary is still lingering in the park after she left the office.

Comment: a. has good grammar
b. is bad grammar because a present continuous clause ("is lingering") cannot have a past time ("after she left the office"). Changing "after she left" to "after leaving" would fix this issue

Then the only difference would be the same thing as present continuous vs. present perfect continuous. If you don't know the difference between those two tenses, there's lots of resources available online

Answer (score 1):

No, neither is quite natural.

> Mary is still lingering in the park.

states where she is now, with an element of surprise that she has been there so long. The fact that, earlier, she left the office would be better in a new sentence.

> Mary has been lingering in the park since she left the office.

states when the 'lingering' began. *Still* doesn't fit in this sentence.

Comment: Indeed, though one might push the envelope: Mary has still been lingering in the park ever since I told her not to.

Answer (score 0):

Both are "correct" and yes, slight differences.

A.) There has been an ongoing discussion the last two weeks about Mary spending time lingering in the park — she was told to stop it or face legal action. But, as evidence shows, she has still been lingering in the park since her firing.

B.) I just looked out the window, since everyone should have gone home from work and sure enough, Mary is still lingering in the park after she left the office. I think she's stalking someone.

Might be best to think about what specific idea you're trying to convey and rewriting it?

Comment: Welcome to the forum aldus! In your answers, please try to answer the question directly about what the meaning is, rather than just giving a possible context where those sentences might apply. There's nothing about "ongoing discussion", "legal action" or "looking out the window" implied in the grammar. If you think the OP should rewrite the question, then please do so in a comment, not an answer. Thanks! :)